# Upgraded to 10.04 LTS and cannot startup

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 9.10

I've been running 9.10 on an old Toshiba Satellite laptop for a few months and recently went to upgrade it to 10.04 LTS, using the Update Manager.  After the update, the computer will not boot.  There is an Ubuntu splash screen and then nothing.  Are there any good things to do to troubleshoot?  I've reinstalled 9.10 and can make adjustments before upgrading this time if it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've unplugged any USB devices that may have plugged in. often, USB devices cause startup process to hang. Also search askubuntu.com for similar questions. Lot of people seems to have this issue. (Including me)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not have any USB devices plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent troubleshooting guide when you get the blank screen is availabe at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen. When you begin to troubleshoot with this guide, if you are unable to access the tty using Ctrl+Alt+F2, you can restart the system, and hold right-shift after the bios check to get the grub menu. Then use the second entry, recovery mode, to start the recovery menu. Choose the root entry and you will be able to perform the edits called for. After editing, if asked, choose low graphics mode.